# Tutorial to create phone book contact in Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

Although there are sites out there to help me create a contact, I am still not able to understand how to do it, Can someone give me a pointer/link/suggestion, that teaches me from scratch how to create a phone contact that will eventually show up in phone contacts list. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know of any tutorials to show step by step. These links may help:

1. [Using the Contacts API](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html)
2. [ContactManager - Contact Manager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html)